Task not serialized Caused by java.io.NotSerializableException java.io.PrintStream
I was wondering if you could help me with Lambda Expressions in
Java Spark. When I use Lambda Expressions in Java Spark, this code works:
JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = context.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
rdd.foreach(x -> System.out.print(x));

But when I use method reference, This code doesn't work:
JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = context.parallelize(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
rdd.foreach(System.out::print);

The Exception message is:
Task not serializable Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.PrintStream
Could you please clarify whether method references and Lambda expressions in Java are the same thing, and if they are also the same in Scala? Could you also explain why this exception occurred?
